# Access Compute Engine servers from a Kubernetes Pod

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've two projects on Google Cloud, which are connected with VPN Tunnels.

**Networks:**

10.10.0.0/8
10.20.0.0/8

So every VM can access the other VMs from the other network.
So 10.10.0.2 can access 10.20.0.2 and vice versa

I created a Kubernetes cluster in 10.10.0.0/8. The cluster has the **10.24.0.0/14** subnetwork. I created a firewall rule, that the pods can access the 10.10.0.0/8 network, but it doesn't work with the 10.20.0.2 network. Any idea? Can I route the traffic via the VPN tunnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kubernetes on GCP uses advanced routing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#google-compute-engine-gce) for internal traffic. The rule in use assigns the entire 10.0.0.0/8 subnet as being part of the GKE cluster. To route traffic to one of your other subnets within this range, you will have to add another forwarding rule.

You can deploy a [daemonSet to ensure each node includes the new routes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46170) to ensure the GKE cluster can reach both of your other subnets. [This GitHub post](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46170) addresses a similar issue with the same fix.